# Why doesn't the points change? python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Slot Machine Game")
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
window.resizable(False, False)
window["bg"] = "cadetblue3"


canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=screen_width,
                   height=screen_height, background='cadetblue3')
canvas.pack()

cherry_s = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/cherry_s.png"))
cherry_s_label = tk.Label(window, image=cherry_s, relief="ridge")
cherry_s_label1 = tk.Label(window, image=cherry_s, relief="ridge")
cherry_s_label2 = tk.Label(window, image=cherry_s, relief="ridge")
cherry_s_label3 = tk.Label(window, image=cherry_s, relief="ridge")
cherry_s_label4 = tk.Label(window, image=cherry_s, relief="ridge")
lemon_s = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/lemon_s.png"))
lemon_s_label = tk.Label(window, image=lemon_s, relief="ridge")
lemon_s_label1 = tk.Label(window, image=lemon_s, relief="ridge")
lemon_s_label2 = tk.Label(window, image=lemon_s, relief="ridge")
lemon_s_label3 = tk.Label(window, image=lemon_s, relief="ridge")
lemon_s_label4 = tk.Label(window, image=lemon_s, relief="ridge")
seveno_s = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/seveno_s.png"))
seveno_s_label = tk.Label(window, image=seveno_s, relief="ridge")
seveno_s_label1 = tk.Label(window, image=seveno_s, relief="ridge")
seveno_s_label2 = tk.Label(window, image=seveno_s, relief="ridge")
seveno_s_label3 = tk.Label(window, image=seveno_s, relief="ridge")
seveno_s_label4 = tk.Label(window, image=seveno_s, relief="ridge")

canvas.create_rectangle(4, 20, screen_width-10, 130,
                        outline='gray21', width=12)
canvas.create_rectangle(14, 30, screen_width-20, 123,
                        fill='cadetblue3', outline='indianred2', width=8)
cherry_s_label.place(x=22, y=35)
cherry_s_label1.place(x=102, y=35)
cherry_s_label2.place(x=182, y=35)
lemon_s_label.place(x=336, y=35)
lemon_s_label1.place(x=416, y=35)
lemon_s_label2.place(x=496, y=35)
seveno_s_label.place(x=650, y=35)
seveno_s_label1.place(x=730, y=35)
seveno_s_label2.place(x=810, y=35)
cherry_s_label3.place(x=964, y=35)
cherry_s_label4.place(x=1044, y=35)
seveno_s_label3.place(x=1124, y=35)
lemon_s_label3.place(x=screen_width-275, y=35)
lemon_s_label4.place(x=screen_width-195, y=35)
seveno_s_label4.place(x=screen_width-111, y=35)


logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/logo4.png"))
logo_label = tk.Label(window, image=logo, background='cadetblue3')
logo_label.place(x=screen_width/2, y=2, anchor='n')
one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/one.png"))
one_label = tk.Label(window, image=one, background='cadetblue3')
one_label2 = tk.Label(window, image=one, background='cadetblue3')
two = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/two.png"))
two_label = tk.Label(window, image=two, background='cadetblue3')
two_label2 = tk.Label(window, image=two, background='cadetblue3')
three = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("imge/three.png"))
three_label = tk.Label(window, image=three, background='cadetblue3',)
one_label.place(x=142, y=118, anchor='n')
one_label2.place(x=456, y=118, anchor='n')
two_label.place(x=1084, y=118, anchor='n')
two_label2.place(x=screen_width-155, y=118, anchor='n')
three_label.place(x=screen_width/2, y=118, anchor='n')



canvas.create_rectangle(386, 166, 1134, 660, outline='gray21', width=15)
canvas.create_rectangle(396, 176, 1124, 650,
                        fill='white', outline='indianred2', width=15)


points = 0
points_label = tk.Label(window, text=f"Points: {points}", font=(
    "Arial", 20), background='cadetblue3')
points_label.place(x=760, y=600, anchor='n')



canvas.create_rectangle(236, 236, 1284, 584, outline='gray21', width=15)
canvas.create_rectangle(246, 246, 1274, 574,
                        fill='cadetblue1', outline='indianred2', width=15)

canvas.create_rectangle(296, 296, 524, 524, outline='gray21', width=30)
canvas.create_rectangle(646, 296, 874, 524, outline='gray21', width=30)
canvas.create_rectangle(996, 296, 1224, 524, outline='gray21', width=30)
canvas.create_rectangle(296, 296, 524, 524, outline='indianred2', width=15)
canvas.create_rectangle(646, 296, 874, 524, outline='indianred2', width=15)
canvas.create_rectangle(996, 296, 1224, 524, outline='indianred2', width=15)

symbol_images = [
    "imge/symbol/seveno.png",
    "imge/symbol/cherry.png",
    "imge/symbol/lemon.png",
]

symbol_images_tk = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(
    Image.open(image)) for image in symbol_images]

label1 = tk.Label(window, image=random.choice(
    symbol_images_tk), borderwidth=10, relief="sunken")
label2 = tk.Label(window, image=random.choice(
    symbol_images_tk), borderwidth=10, relief="sunken")
label3 = tk.Label(window, image=random.choice(
    symbol_images_tk), borderwidth=10, relief="sunken")

label1.place(x=300, y=300)
label2.place(x=650, y=300)
label3.place(x=1000, y=300)


def spin_machine():
    global points

    label1.configure(image=random.choice(symbol_images_tk))
    label2.configure(image=random.choice(symbol_images_tk))
    label3.configure(image=random.choice(symbol_images_tk))

    label1_image = label1.cget("image")
    label2_image = label2.cget("image")
    label3_image = label3.cget("image")
    if label1_image == label2_image == label3_image:
        if label1_image == symbol_images_tk[0]:
            points += 3
        elif label1_image == symbol_images_tk[1]:
            points += 1
        elif label1_image == symbol_images_tk[2]:
            points += 1
    elif (label1_image == label2_image == symbol_images_tk[1] and label3_image == symbol_images_tk[0]) or (label1_image == label3_image == symbol_images_tk[1] and label2_image == symbol_images_tk[0]) or (label3_image == label2_image == symbol_images_tk[1] and label1_image == symbol_images_tk[0]):
        points += 2
    elif (label1_image == label2_image == symbol_images_tk[2] and label3_image == symbol_images_tk[0]) or (label1_image == label3_image == symbol_images_tk[2] and label2_image == symbol_images_tk[0]) or (label3_image == label2_image == symbol_images_tk[2] and label1_image == symbol_images_tk[0]):
        points += 2

    points_label.config(text=f"Points: {points}")


window.bind('<space>', lambda event: spin_machine())


window.mainloop()
```

Sorry for the code mess.
I want the code to add points as shown when I run code,
but the points doesn't change from 0!
I've been searching for 2 hours and don't know why.

I'm still learning English, so my sentences might be awkward.
Please let me know if you don't understand my writing.

I think the problem is my messy conditional statements, but I'm not sure...
My coding skills don't allow me to come up with a different syntax

++
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDDrn.png)
I want it to add points like the "power up" in the picture.
I'd like this to be added to the points below in real time.

Comment: Would you try making a minimum reproducible example and update the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77374679/edit) your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, do we really need all of the images to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @TRCK I'm not sure exactly what the minimum reproducible example is, but I think it would be hard to implement in code, so I've added a picture. Please check it out!

Comment: @nokla This is what I intended.........
seven*3 -> +3points / 
cherry*3 -> +1point / 
lemon*3 -> +1point / 
cherry*2 + seven*1 -> +2points / 
lemon*2 + seven*1 -> +2points

Comment: It's failing because the `image` option retrieved from your Labels will never compare as equal to the original PhotoImage object - that value has been translated from Python to Tcl, and then back to Python, and is no longer the same type of object at all.  You need to compare against `str(symbol_images_tk[X])` instead.

Comment: @jasonharper I fixed it, and it work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you so much, you saved my life. I hope everything you do works out and you are always happy. Thank you from the bottom of my heart. I don't know if it's night or day for you, but whatever time zone you're in, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points are never increased. The points_label
works just fine if the points variable is increased.

But the `if label1_image == symbol_images_tk[0]:`
is never true

Because the image in label1_image is one of:

```
pyimage8, pyimage9, pyimage10
```

but the images you are comparing them to are:

```
<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x00000250FC569F90>, 
<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x00000250FC56A0E0>, 
<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x00000250FC56A1D0>
```

Comment: I just realized that the image inside the label_image is like that! I actually just fixed code but didn't really understand why it works, but your post helped me understand the reason. I won't make the same mistake in the future.... Thanks for the kind explanation, have a nice day!!!!!!!!!